# ExtJs combobox not setting value

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs6

I have a multiselect combobox which is targetcombo of another combobox.

Following are some values from database.

101 - Pink
102 - Red
103 - Dark Blue

I am setting value of combobox using setValue. But I found that it works only if the value does not contain space. 
For example-

```
combobox1.setValue(101);   // Works
combobox1.setValue(102);   // Works
combobox1.setValue(103);   // Does Not Work
```

Also,

```
var val = '101,102';
combobox1.setValue(val.split(',')); // Works well. Displays 'Pink, Red'
```

But

```
var val = '101,103';
combobox1.setValue(val.split(',')); // Displays only 'Pink'
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? or missed anything. Is the issue relalted to targetcombo.
Please help.

Comment: I have created fiddle for you https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1p50 , the setValue(103) works for me. But I don't understand what you mean with that value split. You can have multiple values there? It does not work for me. Could you recreate your exact problem with the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Ext.form.field.Tag. Because Combo multiselect is deprecated since version 5.1.0.

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.Tag', {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'tagfield',
            id: 'tagF',
            valueField: 'value',
            store: 'CustomStore',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, e) {
                Ext.first('#tagF').setValue(101)
            },
            text: '101'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, e) {
                Ext.first('#tagF').setValue(102)
            },
            text: '102'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, e) {
                Ext.first('#tagF').setValue(103)
            },
            text: '103'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, e) {
                var val = '101,102';
                Ext.first('#tagF').setValue(val.split(','));
            },
            text: 'split'
        }
    ]

});
```